# why there is this contradiction in this IF statement line of code?

Tags: javascript

Here I don't understand why contradiction the default condition in the statement `awaitingNextValue = false;` is doing since the value of the if is `awaitingNextValue === true`?

Does this false statement locking the condition after the if is executed ?

```
if (awaitingNextValue) {
    calculatorDisplay.textContent = number;
    awaitingNextValue = false;
} else {
```

Full code

```js
const calculatorDisplay = document.querySelector('h1');
const inputBtns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const clearBtn = document.getElementById('clear');



let firstValue = 0;
let operatorValue = '';
let awaitingSecondValue = false;




function sendNumberValue(onDisplayNumber) {
  if (awaitingSecondValue === true) {
    calculatorDisplay.textContent = onDisplayNumber;
    awaitingSecondValue = false;
  } else {
    //if on display = 0 then add numubr Else add another number to the number on dislpay that is not 0 
    const onDisplayValue = calculatorDisplay.textContent
    calculatorDisplay.textContent = onDisplayValue === '0' ? onDisplayNumber : onDisplayValue + onDisplayNumber;
  }
}
```

Comment: So you wondering why it flips if from true to false?? Probably so the next time it runs it goes into the else. Hard to tell without seeing all the code.

Comment: There is no contradiction here. If you drive a car or ride a motorcycle you do this every day: IF CAR ENGINE IS OFF { TURN CAR ENGINE ON }. You do this check mentally every day -- you don't turn the engine on if it is already on. If there is no contradiction for you to turn your car engine on why should there be a contradiction to stop waiting for next value when you've found the next value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep state when you program. One way is to use a boolean to hold the state. Example would be if a feature is active and you want to enable it or disable it.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");

var state = false;
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (state) {
    console.log("turn off");
    state = false;
  } else {
    console.log("turn on");
    state = true;
  }
  document.body.classList.toggle("active", state);
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button>toggle</button>
```